# How to filter geoserver layer group using cql filter

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers, geoserver

I am trying to use cql filter with geoserver layer group. With only layer I can achieve filtering using **CQL_FILTER**. Here is geoserver' s test page and shows attributes.[image: attributes of layer group].
![geoserver]
Without layer group, I mean if I just use layer. following code can filter wms layer.
    `STATUS=4`.

So how can I filter layer group with cql_filters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general answer is simple: you don't filter a group with CQL filter.

Getting into specifics, you can apply a single filter to the layer group, but it has to be valid for each and every layer in the group, which often is not the case.
When you want to filter, it's best to split up the group into its individual layers, and apply a CQL_FILTER list (CQL filters separated by `;`, one filter for each of them.